# get find_elements_by_xpath to return 'none' or empty string when element not found :signal missing elements in sequence with selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract some attributes from this webpage. 
url='http://m.search.allheart.com/?q=stethoscope'

I wrote the following xpaths for this -:

```
XPATH,ATTRIBUTE='XPATH','ATTRIBUTE'
NUM_RESULTS='NUM_RESULTS'
URL='URL'
TITLE='TITLE'
PROD_ID='PROD_ID'
IS_SALE='IS_SALE'
CURRENCY='CURRENCY'
REGULAR_PRICE='REGULAR_PRICE'
SALE_PRICE='SALE_PRICE'

conf_key={

NUM_RESULTS : {XPATH :'//div[@id="sort-page"]//div[@id="options" and @class="narrowed"]//hgroup[@id="sort-info" and @class="clearfix"]/h2', ATTRIBUTE:''} ,
URL : {XPATH:'//span[@class="info"]//span[@class="swatches clearfix product-colors"]//span[@class="price"]',ATTRIBUTE:'href'} ,
TITLE : {XPATH:'//div[@id="sort-results"]//li[@class="item product-box"]//span[@class="info"]//span[@class="title"]',ATTRIBUTE:''} ,
PROD_ID : {XPATH:'//div[@id="sort-results"]//li[@class="item product-box"]//span[@class="info"]//span[@class="swatches clearfix product-colors"]',ATTRIBUTE:'id'} ,
IS_SALE : {XPATH :'//div[@id="sort-results"]//li[@class="item product-box sale"]', ATTRIBUTE:''} ,
REGULAR_PRICE : {XPATH :'//div[@id="sort-results"]//li[@class="item product-box"]//span[@class="info"]//span[@class="price"]' , ATTRIBUTE:''} ,
SALE_PRICE : {XPATH :'//div[@id="sort-results"]//li[@class="item product-box sale"]//span[@class="info"]//span[@class="price"]' , ATTRIBUTE: '' } ,
}

 chromedriver = "/usr/local/CHROMEDRIVER"
 desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
 os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
 driver.get(url)
```

The idea is to extract the attributes from the 1st search page to get the name , url, title, regular price & sale price.

Skipping the rest of the code.. and later extract the text through a for loop.
When I try to get the items on sale,

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(conf_key[SALE_PRICE][XPATH])
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(conf_key[REGULAR_PRICE][XPATH])
```

**However this gives me , regular_price,sale_price,is_sale as** 
['$5.98', '$5.98', '$24.98', '$3.98', '$6.98', '$13.98', '$24.98', '$19.98', '$18.98', '$3.98', '$5.98', '$24.98', '$12.98', '$24.98'] ['$49.99', '$96.99'] [1, 1]

while I would like -:

```
['$5.98', '$5.98', '$24.98','$49.99', '$3.98', '$6.98', '$13.98', '$24.98', '$19.98', '$18.98', '$3.98', '$5.98',  '$96.99', '$24.98', '$12.98', '$24.98']
['','', '24.98', '' , '' ....]
[0, 0, 1, 0 , 0 ...]
```

**Question -:** 
**I would like to force the driver to return '' (or any placeholder) , so that I can have the signal that the product was not on sale.** 
The webpage will either have the class - : "item product-box" , or "item product-box-sale "

Also, I do not want to hard code this, since I need to repeat this logic for a set of web-pages. How can I do this better without looping through li[0], li[1] .. and so on. 
Is there any method that exists to signal that class was not present when scanned in order ?

**Using the Xpath's defined above, I do get the rest of the container correctly as -:**

```
SEARCH_PAGE
244 Items ['ah426010', 'ahdst0100', 'ahdst0500blk', 'ahd000090', 'ahdst0600', 'pms1125', 'ahdst0400bke', 'ahdst0400blk', 'adc609', 'ma10448', 'ma10428', 'pm121', 'pm108', 'pm122']  ['allheart Discount Dual Head Stethoscope', 'allheart Discount Single Head Stethoscope', 'allheart Cardiology Stethoscope', 'allheart Disposable Stethoscope', 'allheart Discount Pediatric / Infant Stethoscope With Interchangeable Heads Stethoscope', 'Prestige Medical Ultra-Sensitive Dualhead Latex Free Stethoscope', 'allheart Smoke Black Edition Clinical Stainless Steel Stethoscope', 'allheart Clinical Stainless Steel Stethoscope', 'ADC Adscope-Lite 609 Lightweight Double-Sided Stethoscope', 'Mabis Dispos-A-Scope Nurse Stethoscope', 'Mabis Spectrum Nurse Stethoscope', 'Prestige Medical Clinical Lite Stethoscope', 'Prestige Medical Dual Head Stethoscope', 'Prestige Medical Sprague Rappaport Stethoscope']
```

And I need to get the lists of same length, corresponding to each of these, for Regular & sale price(and is_sale flag)

Answer (score 1):

find_elements_by_X return a list of WebElements which each of them may call find_elements_by_X.

1. Use find_elements_by_X to get a list of all the products within the page.
2. Iterate through them all

   1. use find_elements_by_X (on the current product) to get specific element like cur_price or is_on_sale.
   2. Don't forget to initialize a default value.
   3. Store the informations in a structure (map, class, tuple).  Note it is easy to specify a default value in a class using __ init __()

I find css selector easier to read than xpath IMO.  Try it using google chrome console (F12) + right click + copy CSS path.   https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors